# Changing A UIViewCOntroller To A UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I've created a UIViewController and xib for a login screen. It has now occurred to me that my UIViewController actually needs to be a UINavigationController. I want to push a logged in screen once the login happens and have the back button as a logout button going back to the login screen

The problem I have is that when I change my controller header from

```
@interface AccountView : UIViewController
```

to

@`interface AccountView : UINavigationController`

All of the assets in my nib such as textfields dont show up anymore.

Could sombody explain this to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the navigationcontroller is a type of viewcontroller, it is not intended to be used all on its own.  What you're better off doing, is simply leaving everything exactly the way you had it, and create a new UINavigationController to wrap around it.

Comment: Hi, to elaborate, are you suggesting making something like LoginViewNavigationController and giving it a member named LoginViewController (the existing vie controller I have). Then Pushing that controller onto the LoginViewController?

Comment: You only need one navigation controller, it has an initial view controller that you can set to be one of yours (example LoginViewController) then when the login process is complete, you push whatever your next view controller is onto the NavCon